# How to assign the return value of a method that can raise an error?

Tags: ponylang

In pony if there is a method on a class that can raise an error we use the `?` operator to call the method in a `try...end` block. For example:

```
let my_third_list = List[String].from(["First"; "Second"; "Third"])
try env.out.print(list.apply(1)?) end // Second
```

But what if I want to assign the return value of `apply` method to a name like `item` and then print item

```
let my_third_list = List[String].from(["First"; "Second"; "Third"])
try let item = list.apply(1)? end // Second
env.out.print(item)
```

compiler says `can't find declaration of 'item'`

How do I do that? and what is the best way of doing things in these cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All "statements" are expressions in Pony, so you can put an assignment outside the `try` block, such

```
let item = try list.apply(1)? else "<notfound>" end
env.out.print(item)
```

The `else` will be required, since a rvalue must be available.